# OpenCV+Python+HOG proper location argument for "compute" function

Tags: python, opencv

I'm running OpenCV 2.4.6 and Python 2.7, and I'm newly on Python programming.
I need to call the "compute" function of HoGDescriptor Class in my Python scripts.
One of the arguments are the location where the hog descriptors will be calculated (and returned).
In c++ this argument is vector& type. But, in Python, I tried some array or mat combinations and it didn't work.
I copy below the code (it's very simple).

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2  

# read INRIAPerson sample  
i = cv2.imread('crop_000023a.png',0)  
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()  

# let say I want to caculate hog descriptors in the roi
# being at (2,3) position of the image  
r=[1,2]  
descriptors = hog.compute(i,hog.blockStride,hog.cellSize,r)
```

I obtain this error

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 descriptors = hog.compute(i,hog.blockStride,hog.cellSize,r)
>   TypeError: locations

If I make something like

```
r=mat([1,2]) or r=array([1,2]) or r=array([1,2],ndmin=2)
```

It crashed.

Does any one know how to pass the correct arguments to this function in Python?

Thanks in advance,

Pablo Negri

Comment: Dear all,  
The correct way to state the roi coordinates for the locations argument in function HoGDescriptor.compute() is:    

    r=[[1,2]]  
Regards,
Pablo

Comment: Is your problem solved ? Then you can write it as an answer and accept it. It will help others. As a matter of fact, there are not much examples on how to use HOGDescriptor in OpenCV-Python.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are trying to compute a descriptor too close to the image boundary?
Try setting `r` to a location that is at least 8 pixels away from image boundary.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's check if `hog.compute` has some documentation:

```
>> print hog.compute.__doc__
```

which gives:

```
compute(img[, winStride[, padding[, locations]]]) -> descriptors
```

hmmm, maybe we should set `locations` to simply a tuple of tuples? let's try it:

```
r = ((100, 200), ) # for now let's stay away from the boundaries
descriptors = hog.compute(i, hog.blockStride, hog.cellSize, r)
print descriptors.shape
```

and sure enough we get:

```
(3780, 1)
```

Voila! problem solved.